# Angular2 DateTime parse error

Tags: angular, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I want to create fields such as create date, update date, etc.

But when these dates are shown, the minute is 0-9, it shows **HH:2:ss** but it should logically say **HH:02:ss**.

Inside the file that came to me from the Network tab;

[Network Tab - The incoming data is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTYL8.png)

This is the frontend display format;

[Frontend Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAqkT.png)

```
<div style="display:flex;">
   <span class="editlabel form-control">{{ 'created_at' }} :</span>
   <div class="form-addcontrol form-control"> {{data.created_at | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"}}</div>
</div>
```

I did some research, but nobody mentioned it. I will be glad if you help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert "data.created_at" to Date format and then you can use DatePipe

1. Replace Symbol which split time and date ("T").
2. Parse all numbers in array.
3. Create date `new Date(year, month, day, hours, mins, seconds)`.
4. Use DatePipe.

Comment: But it's already date format, Print {{data.created_at}} without using pipe;
**2017-07-24T11:02:51.511061Z**

Comment: I guess the **'mm'** works like the **'m'**. That's 1 digit.

Comment: If i try new Date("2017-07-24T11:02:51"), i can use DatePipe, i thisnk problem in ".511061Z"

Comment: Apply ".toUTCString()" method on your Date

Comment: I found the problem, problem at **@angular/common version**. There is such a bug in my version. Updating my version solved the problem. In the meantime, thank you very much for taking the time to help me :)